# Yii: Import CSV Data and save to database

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I want to save my CSV File data to my database and using "Load Data Infile" as-

```
$sql="LOAD DATA INFILE '".$tempLoc."'
      INTO TABLE `tbl_csv`
  FIELDS
  TERMINATED BY ','
  ENCLOSED BY '\"'
  LINES
  TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
 (`mobile`, `name`, `email`) ";
```

I keep getting syntax errors for this query statement.

Error: CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 13 Can't get stat of '/tmp/phpikiYm6' (Errcode: 2).  //tmp/phpikiYm6 is the file name

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but I have no much reputations to comment on your question, however I cant see that you give the file extension to the query, have you tried:

$sql="LOAD DATA INFILE '".$tempLoc.".csv'
      INTO TABLE `tbl_csv`
  FIELDS
  TERMINATED BY ','
  ENCLOSED BY '\"'
  LINES
  TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
 (`mobile`, `name`, `email`) ";

Comment: Yes I have tried it and still gives me the same error

Comment: please check this: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,588675,588814#msg-588814
I hope this helps

Comment: if you are using apache server just give a permission for the user that the webserver runs under Apache to read and execute, if you are using IIS, then give a permission for IIS_IUSRS to read and execute

Answer (score 0):

Follow given checks to fix this problem :

perror 13
OS error code 13: Permission denied

Check these variables (using SHOW VARIABLES):

```
have_csv = YES
local_infile = ON
```

If those are correct, then...

The .csv file, I think, needs to be readable and locatable by the "mysql" user. Note that both "r" and "x" is needed on directories to let a user 'read' and 'search' the directory.

Suggest you change permissions on the file and directories of this part to 777: